# How to facilitate search and look-up from outside?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Given a master contract that continually generate child contracts, how to facilitate outsider to read some data located in the child contracts. In other words, how to publish the addresses of the Childs contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are discussing of a lot of contracts, the only possibility is to find a key that the user can use for searching and to trace the various child writing in a mapping in the root contract.

Something like:

```
Mapping contractTree (<key type> -> address);
```